# Retrieve product_template images stored in database odoo 13

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-10

I have nodejs server and connected to postgres using pg module. the data binary field in the ir_attachment table is empty. The images might be stored in the windows directory. i can only retrieve the file name and the checksum. how to put things together and generate a url. I am using odoo version 13. please help

I tried to use the odoo url example: http://example.com/web/image?model=pos.category&id=5&field=image_128 but the image does not preview.

[image]

Comment: Do you have more than one database in your setup? Because some controllers like the image controller probably won't work with more than one database.

Comment: No i have only one database

Comment: @CZoellner I have only one database

Comment: Okay, i can see you only have one database. So it could be a access rights problem. Oh and you should change the URL in your question, because everybody can access your system right now or hack it or whatever.

Comment: @CZoellner thanks. I changed the access rule in the setting developer mode of odoo but didnt changed anything. does it need any special access right?

Comment: I'm actually not really sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Example of permitting public users in the security file. At first I placed base.group_public above base.group_user. But it didn't work.

```
access_modulename_planned_locations,modulename.planned.locations,model_modulename_planned_locations,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
access_modulename_planned_locations,modulename.planned.locations,model_modulename_planned_locations,base.group_public,1,0,0,0
```

Comment: What actually worked for me is this (without group name altogether):
access_modulename_planned_locations,modulename.planned.locations,model_modulename_planned_locations,,1,0,0,0